# Detect when YARN kill container

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have MR2 job on Java.
Is it possible to detect and process container kill inside container?
I've tried to use code like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Hooker(this));
```

but there is no logs from Hooker class instance was found.
Maybe is possible to get java heap dump for this container?

Kill reason is

```
Container [pid=35696,containerID=container_1509737408754_96482_01_000384] is running beyond physical memory limits. 
Current usage: 2.0 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.6 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container. Dump of the process-tree for container_1509737408754_96482_01_000384 : |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE |- 35696 35694 35696 35696 (bash)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the child process for that, use the following code and add the filter to detect yarn kill.

```
public class YarnLog {
//
public static void getYarnLog(String appid) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("yarn logs -applicationId %s", appid));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I mean I need detect event inside mapper, not after job fails.